# Input file in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5

I'm trying to upload a file, but it fails when the request lands to the controller.
With fails i mean that if i try `$request->hasFile("filename")` always returns false.

Is there some specific field that I have to specify in the view?

**This is a snippet of the view:**

```
<body>
    <form action="{{url('dev/tester')}}" method="POST">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <button type="submit">Test</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

**And here is the controller**

```
class Tester extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->hasFile('file'))
        {
            dd('Got the file');
        }

        dd('No file');
    }

    public function testView()
    {
        return view('tests.file_upload');
    }
}
```

I always get returned 'No file'.

Any clue? I've even check the php.ini to see if there was a size limitation but it's all set to 32M as MAMP's pro default settings...

Comment: you are not sending enctype="multipart/from-data" from you from

Comment: what a shame! thanks @Imtiaz Pabel! These are the kind of mistakes that makes you loose a whole day! :D If you want to answer the question I will up vote it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check if you may have forgotten to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in `form`

Answer (score 11):

You must enabling upload form to your form,

there is 2 ways to do it :

1. By using HTML

   ```
   <form action="{{url('dev/tester')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   ```
2. By using laravel Form & HTML (https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html)

   ```
   {!! Form::open( [ 'action' => url( 'dev/tester' ), 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true ] ) !!}
       // Your form
   {!! Form::close() !!}
   ```

This should work like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the `enctype="multipart/from-data"` to your form, then it should work!

Comment: As I said in the previous comment these are that kind of forgiveness that helps you to lose a whole day (ironic) :D Thanks!