# Laravel 5.8 broken image upload

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an image upload in one of my recipe applications that has been working fine up until this point. It suddenly broke and it will only allow me to post my recipe if I don't upload an image and I let it revert back to the default "noimage.jpg". Could somebody take a look at my ogic and see where I'm going wrong? I don't understand where it is breaking. Thank you.

**Controller store function**

```
// Handle File Upload 
        if($request->hasfile('recipeImage')){
            // Get filename with extension
            $fileameWithExt = $request->file('recipeImage')->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($fileameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just extension
            $extension = $request->file('recipeImage')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $request->file('recipeImage')->storeAs('public/recipe_images', $fileNameToStore);
        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
        }


        $recipe = new Recipe;
            $recipe->author = auth()->user()->username;
            $recipe->title = $request->input('title');
            $recipe->description = $request->input('description');
            $recipe->ingredients = $request->input('ingredients');
            $recipe->directions = $request->input('directions');
            $recipe->recipeImage = $fileNameToStore;
            $recipe->prepTime = $request->input('prepTime');
            $recipe->cookTime = $request->input('cookTime');
            $recipe->servings = $request->input('servings');
            $recipe->calories = $request->input('calories');
            $recipe->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
            $recipe->save();
```

**Blade view with form**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ action('RecipesController@store') }}" id="submitRecipeForm">
    <div class="photoUploadInput">
                    <label for="imageUpload">
                        <input type="file" id="imageUpload" name="recipeImage">
                    </label>
                    <span>Add a photo of your recipe!</span>
                </div>
```

Let me know if you need to see anymore code. Thank you

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: No errors. It is just redirecting me back to the create view without errors.

Comment: So is $request->file('recipeImage') just returning null? dd($request->file('recipeImage'));

Comment: I'm not able to  dd($request->file('recipeImage'));. As soon as I submit the form with a selected file, it redirects me back to the same page I was on and doesn't submit anything. I tried the  dd($request->file('recipeImage')); before my "Handle image upload" logic and it still doesn't work. There is something strange going on with the upload input it seems like?

Comment: If you put the dd() at the top of your function then you should no longer being redirected and  it should show the results of the dd(). If it still redirects you than you definitely have something wonky going on. Haha

Comment: @ImJT I put the dd() at the top of the file this time and it returns null. Any thoughts on where I need to make adjustments?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192231/discussion-between-imjt-and-carlstrom96).

Comment: Your form is missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119094/input-file-in-laravel-5-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `enctype` attribute of your form to `multipart/form-data`.

```
<form method="POST" 
    action="{{ action('RecipesController@store') }}" 
    id="submitRecipeForm" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```